# Should answers credit inspiration?

Tags: discussion, answers

I'm new to WB (not SE), and I've posted a couple of answers, but I wasn't sure if I should credit my inspirations for ideas, or provide links to stories with the kind of idea I'm thinking of. For example, if I give an answer where I suggest a desert planet where water is very scarce and is effectively used as currency, should I add "a bit like Dune"? Does that add to the questioner's understanding of the answer, or (given this is a site about building original worlds) does it inhibit the imagination, and make the answer worse?

(Related to, but not the same as [Are answers solely referencing novels/movies/etc. okay?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1731/are-answers-solely-referencing-novels-movies-etc-okay))

Answer (score 6):

That really depends on what you mean by inspiration.

- If it's just a related idea that didn't directly lead to your answer then there is no need.
- If something is a close match then it might make sense to credit it.
- If your answer is very similar to or builds on something else then you should definitely credit it.

Really the things to keep in mind are:

Did the other person contribute a significant amount to this answer?

- If so it's only polite to credit them (and the license may require it).

Does including the reference/inspiration improve my answer?

- If so then it makes sense to include it.

For example if all you are doing is talking about a Desert World then Dune is probably not relevant. However if talking about something similar to Spice or Sandworms then it becomes much more so.

Answer (score 2):

I am always adding the inspiration both to the questions and answers. I think it gives people better understanding of what is on my mind.

Example of question: [Hiding own space program](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/14460/hiding-own-space-program)

Example of answer (where I also quoted Dune): [Magivore - designing a magic 'eater'](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/13129/magivore-designing-a-magic-eater/13133#13133)