# Is it proper to make questions about typical created worlds?

Tags: discussion, questions

It's not strange to look at already existing worlds that have characteristics in common with the world you are creating in order to get some inspiration or to avoid using stereotypes.

Would it be a good question, if someone ask for an explanation to something that is already done but he doesn't know how it fits in his setting or if it would be a good addition to his world? Also, questioning why certain types of worlds tend to have the same approach to something would be acceptable?

Comment: If you have a question draft you can always test it in the [Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4835/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) on Meta to get feedback on whether it's on-topic or not and if there is anything else that could be improved. If something fits into a setting sounds opinion-based and is basically up to the authors taste and the intended audience. Why certain world tend to have the same approach sounds interesting, but also a bit opinion-based as we don't know for sure what the authors intentions were. I recommend posting your ideas in the Sandbox.

Comment: Related: [Is there room in WorldBuilding for asking about the feasibility of science fiction ideas, which don't relate to building worlds?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4924/is-there-room-in-worldbuilding-for-asking-about-the-feasibility-of-science-ficti)

Comment: In addition to what @Secespitus said, there is also value in finding a target specific Q/A on SE for an explanation of what your wondering about. There is also the this chat room were you may be able to get non technical answers http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17213/the-factory-floor Its format, in this context tends to be a bit more flexible in terms of getting your question (as stated in this question) answered in a way that allows you to choose if it is something you want to include.

Comment: Related: [Is a “real world” question off topic?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3872/29) and [Are answers solely referencing novels/movies/etc. okay?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1731/29)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are just asking about world already built, this site is not suitable. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/ or https://movies.stackexchange.com/ would probably be a better fit.

If there is some element you want to implement in your world, it is OK to ask about it, provided that:

1. Question will contain all the data needed and
2. Question will contain all constrains you want

It is *not* acceptable to ask question in a way that only fans of certain anime / tv show / book series would understand, and it is *not* acceptable to dismiss an answer only because *show did it differently*, when such restriction was not present in the question itself.

As for "questioning why certain types of worlds tend to have the same approach to something" - it is not acceptable, at least not when stated this way. We cannot know what all these authors were thinking so this could be closed as primarily opinion based. There is no actual problem to be solved, [as noted in help center](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), and since it is not about building a new world, it is simply off topic. If you are building a new fictional world, and want to know if such elements makes sense given *your* constrains, OK, question about that may be all right.

Comment: FWIW, I think my question [How can I explain space travel being accepted and supported in a typical fantasy setting?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/61765/29) is a decent example showing that with some care, this can be done right. No, it isn't tied to a single specific world being built, and even goes so far as to say "typical fantasy setting"; however, it does describe the setting in reasonably sufficient detail for answers to be given; it's limited in what it is asking for; and while the answers do point in somewhat different directions, there *is* a common theme to most of them.